# CYPRESS : Get attribute value then get only the numerical values

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to get the value of the "value" attribute then store it in a variable. After this, I need to remove all non-numeric characters so that I can put this in an assertion that checks if the value is less than a certain value.

```js
<input name="bidAmount" class="form-control marketplace-input" type="text" disabled="" value="MMK&nbsp; 98,158.30">
```

I've played around with the code but I can't seem to get the value of the attribute and also 'process' the value so that I can use an assertion on it.

```js
cy.get('[name="bidAmount"]').invoke('attr', 'value').then(($text) => {
  const num = parseFloat($text.text().replace(',', '').replace('MMK', ''))
  expect(num).to.be.lessThan('4999999.00') 
})
```

This is the error message I currently get from the code above.

`TypeError: $text.text is not a function`

Comment: removed '.text()" and it worked. Hehe

Answer (score 2):

You could try `invoke('val')` in your test and please try let me know;

```
cy.get('[name="bidAmount"]').invoke('val').then((val) => {
             const num = parseFloat(val.replace(',', '').replace('MMK', ''));
             expect(num).to.be.lessThan('4999999.00');
         })
```